# Wrapfig and text error

Tags: spacing, graphics, line-spacing, wrapfigure, wrapfig

Here's my problem, I'd like for all of the text to be on one side and the image on the other, unfortunately I'm being handed an error on a silver platter. Thank you in advance for your help. Please make it childproof and simple for my walnut brain.

Here's the code:

```
\begin{flushleft}
        \textbf{Question 13:}
\end{flushleft}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{Pictures/test 2 graph 2.png} 
\end{wrapfigure}


\textbf{part a.)}
Using the function on the right, determine the following: 
Is the function even or odd.
\vspace{60pt}


\textbf{part b.)}
What are the roots of the function
\vspace{60pt}


\textbf{part c.)}
What interval is the function increasing and decreasing

\vspace{75pt}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! `wrapfigure` isn't a standard LaTeX environment, so could you please edit your question so that we can reproduce your error? It should start with `\documentclass`, and end with `\end{document}`, but you can delete anything else not related to this question. By the way, you can surround your code with three backticks (`\`\`\``), both before and after, to create a neatly formatted code cell.

Comment: `\par` does not take an argument.

Comment: Note that wrapfigure ignores `\vspace` when calculating how much text to wrap.  Just count the lines of text and use the optional argument.

Comment: I would recommend using minipages instead of wrapfigure most of the time.  You have way more precise control over the layout and fewer bugs, in my experience.